# Не запускается js скрипт

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Что-то делаю видимо не так. Помогите разобраться

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <title>test</title>
    <script>
        function upHend () {
            alert('ddd');
            $("#up").style.color = 'red';
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<button onclick="upHend()">press</button>
<div id="up">qqq</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ну так посмотрите ошибку в конслоли браузера или гадать будет на кофейной гуще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vKs, посмотрите, пожалуйста, документацию по jQuery, например http://jquery.page2page.ru

В вашем случае чтобы изменить стиль, надо применить метод [`css()`](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_CSS):

```
$("#up").css({'color': 'red'});
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Я только начал изучать jquery, поэтому еще наступаю на грабли